# Apportable is not updated to the latest version

Tags: apportable

I am using the free version of the apportable, after updating the apporatable it is showing the current version is "Apportable SDK version release_1.0.34 (1e06..... full)" although on 
their website it is showing the latest version is 1.1.08.1, how to get the latest SDK?

Last update output in terminal:

```
$ apportable --version

Apportable SDK version release_1.0.34 (1e06ded3379bd59161534f679b9bcc3e385b1d95 full)

clang version 7fc8b05e4f57f61dbbbe5c8e62581b0e0c42941e

gdb version b5f29d65da6903ad0570d0c4a887c513367d2778

android sdk version r21.0.1.1

android ndk version r8d.1

ninja version 315d897710c6ca6e7df7d3b0bf68879356841c5d
```

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal, enter:

```
apportable update
```

and

```
apportable update_toolchain
```

This will check for updates and update apportable itself, as well as updating the Android toolchain / SDK stuff. Usually just updating apportable suffices.

If Apportable won't update you can "reset" it by deleting the folder `~/User/.apportable`. In Terminal:

```
rm -rf ~/User/.apportable
```

Then go to the apportable website, download apportable and follow their instructions for first-time setup.

Note that there is a chance that the Starter version may simply lag some version numbers behind the paid versions. I'm not aware of Apportable's versioning strategy but many companies only provide major or critical updates to free editions of their product, they prefer the free version to be stable rather than the latest edition.

Comment: Even after doing '$ apportable update;' apportable is not getting updated; $ apportable update_toolchain; showing all the dependency libraries which are updated to the latest version.

Comment: removed the old apportable, created new account in apportable got a new download link, finally apportable got updated to latest version. Thanks a lot Steffen.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to ensure that you have the latest SDK version selected on your [Account](http://www.apportable.com/account) page in the `SDK Version` section.

I was experiencing the same problem; for some reason an SDK several versions behind was selected on this page.